# Stop ipython from looking in ~/.ipython

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I start my notebook with this command line:

```
ipython3 notebook --profile=/ipython3/profiles/qa-ipython3/ipython_config.py \
                  --ip=0.0.0.0                                               \
                  --port=80                                                  \
                  --no-browser                                               \
                  --notebook-dir=/ipython3/notebooks                         \
                  --ipython-dir=/ipython3/ipython                            \
                  --profile-dir=/ipython3/profiles
```

If I delete `$HOME/.ipython`, I get an exception from ipython:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.ipython'
```

What do I have to do to get `ipython3 notebook` to constrain itself to only `/ipython3/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get IPython looking into a custom directory for its profiles, the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable can be used.

On Win7 I use a start stript which sets the variable before starting the notebook to quickly switch between different profiles and IPython versions like

```
set IPYTHONDIR=PATH/TO/DIR/.ipython
ipython notebook
```

The same should work on unix-like systems as well.
Of course, this does't specify where to serve the notebooks from but only sets the profile dir.

Comment: Do you also set any of `--notebook-dir`, `--ipython-dir`, `--profile-dir`, and `--profile`?

Comment: No, I typically use profile_default located in the targeted IPYTHONDIR so there is no need for additional options with respect to the profile. I get the correct notebook dir by starting the script at the right location.